# Will my new propane gas cooktop smell different that my natural gas cooktop did?

Tags: kitchens

We've moved to a new house and plan to convert the electric cooktop to propane gas. I've noticed that the propane fireplace has a "burnt" odor to it. Now, I'm concerned that my gas cooktop will have that same odor. Is that a common problem, or is the fireplace smell coming from the gas logs?

Comment: At least where I live, propane and natural gas do smell somewhat different when burning.

Answer (score 2):

How long since it was last used? Last Winter?
Many heaters, gas or electric, will smell of burning dust the first couple of times they're fired up after Summer. Only worry if it doesn't go away in a couple of days.

Correctly combusted domestic gas doesn't really smell of anything.

Answer (score 0):

They should smell the same. Both the Propane and Gas are odorless gases that can kill you or explode under the right conditions. Since these "gas" companies want to keep you around, as their customer they add the smell. It is also the law in some countries. Added to both Propane and Gas the supply companies add a smelly harmless chemical called mercaptan to giving it the distinctive “rotten egg” smell. This smell is there so a user can detect a leak, possibly an extinguished pilot light, stove burner on but not lit, etc.

When they burn they can pick up an order from the surround area and or the material they are heating. Both gases should burn with a blue flame if the air and gas mixture is correct. The gas passes through a metering orifice and picks up oxygen (air) to burn. The size of the orifice for natural gas is bigger than the propane because of the service (pressure of gas feeding appliance burner).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a concern.

In a correct installation, I've never noticed a smell when the fuel (propane or natural gas) was being burned. Prior to burning, there is definitely a smell, but not a burnt smell; it's more like a rotten egg smell. A burnt odor coming from a gas fireplace almost certainly means that someone burned something in it they should not have (spy messages, jury notices, wood logs... who knows).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting a burnt smell from propane gas unless the area is contaminated with something that's burning or residue from something that was burning. That's probably what's happening with your fireplace. It's not uncommon for people to add some wood to their gas fireplaces to get the smell of wood burning. Problem is, it doesn't burn completely off the fake gas logs and can linger on for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Propane will have its own unique smell and you wil know about it with there is any kind of leak.

Same with natural  gas. And it is for a reason.

So as far as any other smell, your fireplace issue is not due to propane smell and will not be transferred to stove.   The smell is not from propane which would translate to leak.

Okay. Take care.